Difficult to understand the solution to the travelling salesman problem having Hamiltonian circuits with added length constraint
The travelling salesman problem has been  solved in the below given video, but I didn't understand lower bound computed for the following paths.
I also didn't understand the why Path 8,9 10 and 11 have been called 'first tour', 'better tour', 'inferior tour' and 'optimal tour' respectively.
What  are the meanings of l=24 for Path 8, l=19 for Path 9, l= 24 for Path 10 and l=16 for Path 11?
Path 4: a,e lb=19,
Path 5:a,b,c lb=16,
Path 6:a,b,d lb=16,
Path 7: a,b,e lb=19,
Path 8:a,b,c,d (e,a) l=24 first tour ,
Path 9: a,b,c,e(d,a) l= 19 (better tour),
Path 10: a,b,d,c (e,a) l=24 (inferior tour),
Path 11: a,b,d,e(c,a) l=16 optimal tour.
https://youtu.be/aaaVm6uUY5A
Would any member explain me the travelling salesman problem solved in this video?
Can we solve this problem by another method where conditions of the travelling salesman problem is not satisfied?
The condition is the salesman has to visit each city in the tour  only once and return to the start city.

Every TSP tour uses two edges incident with each node, and an optimal tour cannot do better than using the cheapest two edges per node. Adding these up across all nodes would count $2n$ edges, so divide by $2$ to get a valid lower bound.  If the costs are integer-valued, you can additionally take the ceiling to improve the lower bound (by at most $1/2$).
“First tour” refers to the first tour ($5$-cycle) that is found during the tree search, and its cost $l=24$, obtained by summing the $5$ edge costs in the tour, provides an upper bound on the optimal cost.  “Better tour” is called that because its cost $l=19$ is smaller than $24$, and $19$ becomes the new upper bound.  “Inferior tour” is called that because its cost $l=24$ is worse (higher) than $19$.  “Optimal tour” is called that because its cost $l=16$ matches the lower bound and hence cannot be improved.

I computed lb for node 7 (a,b,e) = (1+3)+ (3+9)+( 1+2) +(4+3) +(2 +9)=37/2 =18.5 rounded off to nearest integer 19. Is this computation correct?

You should round up because $37/2$ is a lower bound and the objective is integer-valued.  This yields $19$, but it is important to disambiguate nearest because $18$ is just as near but provides a weaker lower bound.
